# How todo I use the vertical-align property on <li>s?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the image in every `<li>` without any success.

I tried using `display: table;` on the `<ul>` tag and `display: table-cell;` on the `<li>`.

I tried using `display: table;` on the `<li>` tag and `display: table-cell;` on the `<img>` tag.

Neither of these approaches worked.

```
<div class="slider-container">
            <div class="scroll-left"></div>
            <div class="slider">
                <ul class="slides">

                    <li class="slide">
                        <img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeBig">
                    </li>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeSmall">
                    </li>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <img src="http://exaple.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/images/ginger_Button.png" class="makeBig">
                    </li>

                    <li class="slide">
                        <img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeSmall">
                    </li>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeBig">
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-right"></div> 
        </div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8b47wong/

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your `float: left;` on your `<li>` element. Try to remove it and just add `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`

http://jsfiddle.net/8b47wong/4/

```
.slider .slide {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 19.26em;
    height: 11.1em;
    padding: 0!important;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8b47wong/3/)

In you code add this `position: relative` to `.slider .slide`. Then add to `.slides img`

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same line-height as the height and add vertical-align: middle; to the .slide class and the image itself:

jsfiddle.net/8b47wong/5/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this will help or not, but I've changed a few things (details below) http://jsfiddle.net/8b47wong/2/

#### HTML

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig" />
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeSmall" />
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig" />
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeSmall" />
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.slider-container {
    /* padding-top: 20em; */
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.slider {
    width: 69.8em;
    height: 13.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
}
.slider .slides {
    width: 400em;
    height: 13.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -69.7em;
    display:table-row;
}
.slider .slide {
    width: 19.26em;
    height: 11.1em;
    padding: 0!important;
    /* border: 1px solid red; */
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
.slides img {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.scroll-left {
    background-image: url('http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/arrow_left.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.2em;
    left: 16em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.scroll-right {
    background-image: url('http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/arrow_right.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.2em;
    right: 16em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I added `display:table` to your div, `display:table-row` to your ul, and `display:cell;vertical-align:middle;` to your li. I removed a few other things as well that didn't tie in with the new amendments but I can't remember all of them :P

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can center vertically the images by using:

```
ul { display: table; }
ul li { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
ul li img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

BUT in your case if that's a slider/carousel, probably the `<li>` tags will be floated left and then `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` will not work.

Another thing you can do is to wrap the images in a `div` and put some height... e.g:

```
ul li { float: left; display: table; }
ul li div { display: table-cell; height: 200px; vertical-align: middle; }
ul li div img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="scroll-left"></div>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">

            <li class="slide">
                <div><img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeBig"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <div><img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeSmall"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <div><img src="http://exaple.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/images/ginger_Button.png" class="makeBig"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="slide">
                <div><img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeSmall"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <div><img src="http://exaple.com/Button.png" class="makeBig"></div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-right"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your .slides img class:
`position: relative; top:50; transform: translateY(-50%);`

Like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/8b47wong/7/

```css
.slider-container {
/* padding-top: 20em; */
position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.slider {
width: 69.8em;
height: 13.5em;
overflow: hidden;
/* border: 1px solid black; */
margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider .slides {
display: block;
width: 400em;
height: 13.5em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: inherit !important;
margin-left: -69.7em;
}
.slider .slide {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
width: 19.26em;
height: 11.1em;
padding: 0!important;
/* border: 1px solid red; */
text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.slides img {
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig"/>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeSmall"/>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig"/>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeSmall"/>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig"/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Please update your code 
Need to add these code http://screen.w3.ua/Mar15/14019014.jpg
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8b47wong/1/

```css
.slider-container {
/* padding-top: 20em; */
position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.slider {
width: 69.8em;
height: 13.5em;
overflow: hidden;
/* border: 1px solid black; */
margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
width: 69.8em;
height: 13.5em;
overflow: hidden;
/* border: 1px solid black; */
margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider .slides {
display: block;
width: 400em;
height: 13.5em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: inherit!important;
margin-left: -69.7em;
}
.slider .slide {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
width: 19.26em;
height: 11.1em;
padding: 0!important;
/* border: 1px solid red; */
text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.slider .slide:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    
}
.slides img {
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
}


.scroll-left {
background-image: url('http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/arrow_left.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 3.2em;
left: 16em;
cursor: pointer;
}


.scroll-right {
background-image: url('http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/arrow_right.png');
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 3.2em;
right: 16em;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
   <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">

     <li class="slide">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig">
     </li>
     <li class="slide">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeSmall">
     </li>
     <li class="slide">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig">
     </li>

     <li class="slide">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeSmall">
     </li>
     <li class="slide">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Amarok-icon.png" class="makeBig">
     </li>
       
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please point out what he should change, rather than just repasting an entire block of code.

Comment: @kumar You need to post the actual code changes rather than a link to an image. That image may disappear off the internet and then your post will become useless.